# Compilation error with Jack compiler and generics

Tags: java, android, android-jack-and-jill

I'm using an ORM for android called [Squeaky](https://github.com/auras/squeaky) and it generates code to avoid using reflection. The generated code worked ok when I wasn't using the new jack compiler but with it I get these errors:

> ERROR: C:\...\app\build\generated\source\apt\prod\debug\...\domain\model\WeatherForecast$Configuration.java:24.20: The type WeatherForecast$Configuration must implement the inherited abstract method GeneratedTableMapper.fillRow(WeatherForecast, Cursor, ModelDao, Dao.ForeignRefresh[], TransientCache)
>
> ERROR: C:\...\app\build\generated\source\apt\prod\debug\...\domain\model\WeatherForecast$Configuration.java:43.15:
>   The method fillRow(WeatherForecast, Cursor, ModelDao,
>   Dao.ForeignRefresh[], TransientCache) of type
>   WeatherForecast$Configuration must override or implement a supertype
>   method

Is this actually a bug in the generated code or could it a bug with the compiler?

Here is the generated class method with the problem

```
public final class WeatherForecast$Configuration implements GeneratedTableMapper<WeatherForecast> {
  public static final WeatherForecast$Configuration instance = new WeatherForecast$Configuration();

  FieldsEnum[] fields;

  ForeignCollectionInfo[] foreignConfigs;

  public WeatherForecast$Configuration() {
    this.fields = getFields();
    this.foreignConfigs = getForeignConfigs();
  }

  @Override
  public WeatherForecast createObject(Cursor results) throws SQLException {
    WeatherForecast data = new WeatherForecast();
    return data;
  }

  @Override
  public void fillRow(WeatherForecast data, Cursor results, ModelDao<WeatherForecast> modelDao, Dao.ForeignRefresh[] foreignRefreshMap, TransientCache objectCache) throws SQLException {
    if(!results.isNull(0))data.setStationId(results.getInt(0));
    if(!results.isNull(1))data.setTemperature(results.getFloat(1));
    if(!results.isNull(2))data.setHumidity(results.getInt(2));
    if(!results.isNull(3))data.setForecastCode(results.getInt(3));
    if(!results.isNull(4))data.setStartTime(results.getLong(4));
    if(!results.isNull(5))data.setEndTime(results.getLong(5));
    data.setIcon(results.getString(6));
  }

...
}
```

And the 2 interfaces that are inherited/being used:

GeneratedTableMapper.java

```
public interface GeneratedTableMapper<T> {
    T createObject(Cursor results) throws SQLException;

    void fillRow(T data, Cursor results, ModelDao<T> modelDao, Dao.ForeignRefresh[] foreignRefreshMap, TransientCache objectCache) throws SQLException;

    void assignId(T data, Object val);

    Object extractId(T data);

    void bindVals(SQLiteStatement stmt, T data) throws SQLException;

    void bindCreateVals(SQLiteStatement stmt, T data) throws SQLException;

    String objectToString(T data) throws SQLException;

    boolean objectsEqual(T d1, T d2) throws SQLException;

    TableInfo<T> getTableConfig() throws SQLException;

    void fillForeignCollection(T data, ModelDao<T> modelDao, String fieldName) throws SQLException;

    //Foreign

}
```

Dao.java

```
public interface Dao<T> {
    class ForeignRefresh {
        public final String field;
        public final ForeignRefresh[] refreshFields;

        public ForeignRefresh(String field) {
            this(field, null);
        }

        public ForeignRefresh(String field, ForeignRefresh[] refreshFields) {
            this.field = field;
            this.refreshFields = refreshFields;
        }
    }

    interface QueryModifiers<T> {
        QueryModifiers<T> orderBy(String s);

        QueryModifiers<T> limit(Integer i);

        QueryModifiers<T> offset(Integer i);

        QueryModifiers<T> foreignRefreshMap(ForeignRefresh[] foreignRefreshMap);

        List<T> list() throws SQLException;
    }

    T queryForId(Object id) throws SQLException;

...

    void refresh(T data) throws SQLException;

    void refresh(T data, ForeignRefresh[] foreignRefreshMap) throws SQLException;
...
}
```

Comment: Nevermind. I decided not to use jack anymore and for good reasons as it just got deprecated.